# Конвертировать MP3 в WAV для Speech_Recognition

Tags: python, распознавание-речи, google-speech-recognition

Имею своего бота в ВК и решил сделать ему возможность выполнять функции через Голосовые сообщения. Имею два файла MP3 и OGG,чтобы мне использовать Speech_Recognition мне нужен WAV,но пробовал уже много способов и ничего. Помогите.
Имею вот такой не большой код,чтобы было от чего отталкиваться:

```
url = object['attachments'][0]['audio_message']['link_mp3']
audio = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
f = open('audio_message_{userid}.mp3'.format(userid=userid), "wb")
f.write(audio)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте библиотеку PySoundFile, и метод .read(), вроде с разными форматами работает

import soundfile as sf

sig, samplerate = sf.read('data/test_wav_pcm16.wav')